# How do you pass a value to a custom envelop field using the the JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I am trying to figure out how to pass a value to the custom envelope field I have created. I am currently using the new JS SDK. I am able to pass a value to a custom field for my document but am unsure how to do this for an envelope custom field.

```
data-powerform-fields="signer_UserName=firstname%lastname&signer_Email=ada@example.com&signer_acknowledgement=Read
and accepted." src="//developers.docusign.com/js/docusign.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Docusign engineering team has confirmed the issue. However, we don't anticipate that we can implement a solution immediately. Most likely we'll have a solution later in the beta for Docusign.js.

Answer (score 0):

SDK is simply an API helper. Whatever is available in the API is converted to JS SDK
and for the moment JS SDK seems to be available only in beta: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/introducing-our-javascript-sdk-docusignjs